# ManageYourTeam - Yii - apache error

Tags: apache, url, dynamic, yii

I installed ManageYourTeam app (http://manageyourteam.net/) in my web sever.

I install in (example):

```
/path/public/myt
```

And installation its ok.

In this path (/path/public) there are another urls

```
/path/public/myt
/path/public/app1
/path/public/app2

<private_ip>/myt -> ok
<private_ip>/app1 -> ok
<private_ip>/app2 -> ok
```

Now I added an alias for each webapp:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/app1.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/app2.conf

Alias /app1 /path/app1
<Directory /path/app1/>
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</Directory>
```

to migrate

```
app1 and app2 to /path/app1 and /path/app2
```

and all ok.

```
/path/public/myt
/path/app1
/path/app2

<private_ip>/myt -> ok
<private_ip>/app1 -> ok
<private_ip>/app2 -> ok
```

But when I moved

```
/path/public/myt/ to /path/myt/
```

using the same .conf that app1 and app2 (but changing names)

MYT dont works.

I think that the error is for dynamic urls. Its posible.
Myt is write in Yii framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solution: include in .htaccess RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

```
edit /path/myt/protected/config/main.php
```

Change:

```
'showScriptName' => false
```

to:

```
'showScriptName' => true
```

Now I see "index.php" in url path, but if it necessary, I do.

Comment: Finally Solution: include in .htaccess RewriteBase /<alias>